# Looping through Array Values with $SQL output

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of serialized data that I unserialize and store into an array.

```
$employee_data = unserialize($entry, '63');
```

Which results in an expected output:

> Array ( [0] => 
>       Array ( [First] => Joe 
>               [Last] => Test 
>               [Birth Date] => 01/01/2011 
>               ) 
>           [1] => 
>       Array ( [First] => Mike 
>               [Last] => Miller 
>               [Birth Date] => 01/01/1980 
>               ) 
>           )

Ive been trying, unsuccessfully, to insert these records into a table in MySQL using foreach() or something like:

```
$employee_array = array();
$k = 1;
for($n=0; $n<count($employee_data); $n++ ){
    $employee_array['employee_first_name'.$k] = $employee_data[$n]['First'];
    $employee_array['employee_last_name'.$k] =  $employee_data[$n]['Last'];
    $employee_array['employee_birthdate'.$k] =  $employee_data[$n]['Birth Date'];
$SQL = "INSERT INTO employee_test (
employee_first_name,
employee_last_name,
employee_birthdate
)
VALUES (
'$employee_first_name.$k',
'$employee_last_name.$k',
'$employee_birthdate.$k'
)"
$k++;
};
```

Each employee in the array needs to be entered into a new row in the table, however the number of employees will vary from 1 to 10+

We've tried

```
foreach($employee_array as $key => $value)
```

with the same results.

The actual results we're hoping for is the SQL Statement to be:

```
insert into employee_test(
employee_first_name,
employee_last_name,
employee_birthdate)
VALUES(
'Joe',
'Test',
'01/01/2011');
insert into employee_test(
employee_first_name,
employee_last_name,
employee_birthdate)
VALUES(
'Mike',
'Miller',
'01/01/1980');
```

Comment: Do you need the `$employee_array` or just using it for the INSERT for the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your sql statement is not escaped. For example, a name with an apostrophe like "0'neil" will break your sql. I would also familiarise yourself with php's foreach: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish by adding the index to the name and sql value, but I would do something like this:

```
foreach($employee_data as $key => $value){
    // $employee_array is not necessary 
    $employee_array[$key]['employee_first_name'] = $value['First'];
    $employee_array[$key]['employee_last_name'] =  $value['Last'];
    $employee_array[$key]['employee_birthdate'] =  $value['Birth Date'];
    // Needs escaping
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO employee_test (
employee_first_name,
employee_last_name,
employee_birthdate
)
VALUES (
'{$value['First']}',
'{$value['Last']}',
'{$value['Birth Date']}'
)";
    echo $SQL;
};
```

Comment: Agreed on the apostrophe - Oddly, that is addressed in a sanitization before the names are passed with a "str_replace".  Apparently keeping the apostrophe was deemed unimportant.  Thanks for the suggestion - it appears similar to an approach that was tried earlier but only resulted in one INSERT() statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do here. You are using the `=` operator, effectively setting `$SQL` to a new value each time your loop iterates. If you adapt your code, you will be able to append to `$SQL` variable each time.

```
//I used this array for testing. Comment this out
$employee_data = array(
        0 => array(
                "first" => "test",
                "last"  => "tester",
                "birth date" => "01/01/1970"
            ),
        1 => array(
                "first" => "bob",
                "last"  => "david",
                "birth date" => "02/02/1972"
            ),
    );

    //Start SQL as a blank string
$SQL = "";

//Do your iteration
foreach( $employee_data as $key=>$value ){
    $first     = $value['first'];
    $last      = $value['last'];
    $birthDate = $value['birth date'];

    //append this query to the $SQL variable. Note I use `.=` instead of `=`
    $SQL .= "INSERT INTO employee_test(
                 `employee_first_name`,
                 `employee_last_name`,
                 `employee_birthdate`)
             VALUES(
                 '$first',
                 '$last',
                 '$birthDate'
             );";
}

//output the query
echo $SQL;
```

There are much easier ways of doing this though. Look into prepared statements :)

Comment: Ahhh, sometimes a fresh set of eyes is exactly what is needed.  I completely missed the '=' instead of appending!

Comment: Two huge steps in the right direction.  The $SQL looks exactly as expected however it fails when run via $wpdb->query($SQL).

The echo looks exactly like what I need but it seems to be throwing an incorrect syntax error 1064 error at line 12:
    right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO employee_test(employee_fir'

But copying the echo $SQL and running it in MYSQL inserts both records as expected.

Comment: @kiknit, try amending the code to use backticks in your INSERT statement around each column name, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The first implementation wont work as your calling a variable rather than the key in your array.

```
'$employee_first_name.$k',
```

Should be

```
$employee_array['employee_first_name'.$k]
```

You are also creating the SQL statement every iteration of the for loop, so in this implementation only the last employee will save.

Also I don't see the reasoning in doing it that way anyway you may as well just use the employee_data array and the $k variable can also be made redundant.

```
$SQL = ""; 
for($n=0; $n<count($employee_data); $n++ ){
    $SQL .= "INSERT INTO employee_test (
    employee_first_name,
    employee_last_name,
    employee_birthdate
    ) VALUES (";
    $SQL .= "'".$employee_data[$n]['First']."',";
    $SQL .= "'".$employee_data[$n]['Last']."',";
    $SQL .= "'".$employee_data[$n]['Birth Date']."'";
    $SQL .= ");";
};
```

Ive not tested but it should give you an idea.

You will also have issues with the date formatted that way, Your database would likely require the date in yyyy/mm/dd format

Finally I would not recommend inserting values like this, look at the [PDO library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) for placeholders.